# Device placement with distributed Estimator training + ml-engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to get a trivial estimator to train across 2+ machines on Google Machine Learning Engine. Can't figure out how to indicate device placement.

#### model_fn (part of it)

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  x = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 199, 199, 3])

  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
      conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=16, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
      pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
      conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool1, filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation=tf.nn.relu)
      pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
```

#### config.yaml

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  workerType: standard_gpu
  parameterServerType: large_model
  workerCount: 1
  parameterServerCount: 1
```

The job gets created, but soon gets stuck with the following in the error log (and nothing gets saved to `model_dir`)

[image]

The error message for every device (`worker-replica-0`, `master-replica-0`, and `ps-replica-0`) is the same:

```
# ps and worker: -------------v
message:  "    grpc epoll fd: 3" 

# master ---------------------v
message:  "    grpc epoll fd: 4"
```

## Edit

I've removed the `with tf.device` statements, and the same error shows up. I've  tried deploying to different scaling types, but anything with more than one machine (CPU or GPU) fails the same  way.

Comment: Did you use tf.estimators in TF 1.4? If yes, can you try to call train_and_eval() instead of train() please?

Comment: Correct, 1.4 with estimator API. I'll try `train_and_eval()`. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Using `train_and_eval()` did the trick. Thanks